# Treat UIButton as UILabel in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform, uibutton

How to Treat UIButton as UILabel in cellForRowAtIndexPath, I want to call it at cellForRowAtIndexPath as UILabel.

I get this error :

> cannot assign value of of type String to type UIButton

Am using PFQueryTableViewController.

```
 cell.cityButton = object?.objectForKey("City") as? String

cell.locationLabel.text = object?.objectForKey("eventLocation") as? String
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to set the `cityButton` equal to an (optional) `String`, which will obviously not work. Instead, you want to set the title of the button to that string. Try this:

```
cell.cityButton.setTitle(object?.objectForKey("City") as? String forState: .Normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try w this: `cell.cityButton.setTitle(object?.objectForKey("City") as? String forState: .Normal)`